# Socket.io - How to emit Kotlin object in same way that JS code does?

Tags: javascript, android, kotlin, socket.io

I want to move implementation from react app which is working on Socket.io to my Android app. However, I cannot get the same result from the Kotlin code. I don't have access to the server-side code so I need to map the code running on React side.

Here is working code from react app

```
socket.emit('message', {type: 'image', photo: 'some base64 code'});
```

This is the Kotlin code that I wanted to get the same result on the server side

```
data class Data(var type: String, var photo: String)
```

```
socket?.emit("message", Data("image", "some base64 code"))
```

The socket is configured correctly and all sent values on both platforms are the same but the Kotlin code doesn't give any result on the server's side. How can I get the same 'emit' method call on the Android side?

**EDIT**

I wanted to serialize JS object on my own and emit it through Socket.io but it's also doesn't work on the server-side. The only method that works is passing JS object to emit method.

```
var data = {type: 'image', photo: 'some base64 code'};
var json = JSON.stringify(data);
socket.emit('message', json);
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, by using data class will not convert its data into JSON format when `toString` is called on the instance of it. You need to manually do that. You can use gson library for that.

In your app/build.gradle file, add gson dependency:

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
}
```

Your socket emit call:

```
val data = Data("image", "some base64 code")
socket?.emit("message", Gson().toJson(data))
```

Comment: I've tried to use Json as parameter but it's doesn't works. The only method that works is passing Js object into emit method. So I'm curious about differences.

Comment: Well, gson creates the same json string only with double quotes instead of single quotes. If it is not working then I think, server side implementation should be changed to accept JSON data.